# Touch Input Problems on Immersive Mode on Android

Tags: java, android, frameworks, multi-touch, android-immersive

I have a sample game and enabled `immersive mode` but the right Buttons on the end doesn't work well. When I enable `immersive mode` the `Touch Input` works as it would be a screen with the software buttons though they don't be visible at all.

Every `Touch Input` on the right corner where the software buttons would be if i turn the `immersive mode` off will not work.

I don't know what to do to fix this. I attach the source code [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=45029865089927242452):

Thats my Main game Class:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Immersive Mode
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


      getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                                                                 View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                                                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                                                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                                                                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                                                                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                                                                 | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);


        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 480: 800;
        int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 800: 480;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY); <- INPUT
        screen = getInitScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);
```

The Android `Input class` will initialize this Class

```
package com.kilobolt.framework.implementation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

import com.kilobolt.framework.Pool;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.kilobolt.framework.Pool.PoolObjectFactory;

public class MultiTouchHandler implements TouchHandler {
    private static final int MAX_TOUCHPOINTS = 10;

    boolean[] isTouched = new boolean[MAX_TOUCHPOINTS];
    int[] touchX = new int[MAX_TOUCHPOINTS];
    int[] touchY = new int[MAX_TOUCHPOINTS];
    int[] id = new int[MAX_TOUCHPOINTS];
    Pool<TouchEvent> touchEventPool;
    List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
    List<TouchEvent> touchEventsBuffer = new ArrayList<TouchEvent>();
    float scaleX;
    float scaleY;

    public MultiTouchHandler(View view, float scaleX, float scaleY) {
        PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent> factory = new PoolObjectFactory<TouchEvent>() {
            @Override
            public TouchEvent createObject() {
                return new TouchEvent();
            }
        };
        touchEventPool = new Pool<TouchEvent>(factory, 100);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);

        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        synchronized (this) {
            int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT;
            int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            TouchEvent touchEvent;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOUCHPOINTS; i++) {
                if (i >= pointerCount) {
                    isTouched[i] = false;
                    id[i] = -1;
                    continue;
                }
                int pointerId = event.getPointerId(i);
                if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && i != pointerIndex) {
                    // if it's an up/down/cancel/out event, mask the id to see if we should process it for this touch
                    // point
                    continue;
                }
                switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                    touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
                    touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN;
                    touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
                    touchEvent.x = touchX[i] = (int) (event.getX(i) * scaleX);
                    touchEvent.y = touchY[i] = (int) (event.getY(i) * scaleY);
                    isTouched[i] = true;
                    id[i] = pointerId;
                    touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
                    touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP;
                    touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
                    touchEvent.x = touchX[i] = (int) (event.getX(i) * scaleX);
                    touchEvent.y = touchY[i] = (int) (event.getY(i) * scaleY);
                    isTouched[i] = false;
                    id[i] = -1;
                    touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    touchEvent = touchEventPool.newObject();
                    touchEvent.type = TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED;
                    touchEvent.pointer = pointerId;
                    touchEvent.x = touchX[i] = (int) (event.getX(i) * scaleX);
                    touchEvent.y = touchY[i] = (int) (event.getY(i) * scaleY);
                    isTouched[i] = true;
                    id[i] = pointerId;
                    touchEventsBuffer.add(touchEvent);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isTouchDown(int pointer) {
        synchronized (this) {
            int index = getIndex(pointer);
            if (index < 0 || index >= MAX_TOUCHPOINTS)
                return false;
            else
                return isTouched[index];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getTouchX(int pointer) {
        synchronized (this) {
            int index = getIndex(pointer);
            if (index < 0 || index >= MAX_TOUCHPOINTS)
                return 0;
            else
                return touchX[index];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getTouchY(int pointer) {
        synchronized (this) {
            int index = getIndex(pointer);
            if (index < 0 || index >= MAX_TOUCHPOINTS)
                return 0;
            else
                return touchY[index];
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<TouchEvent> getTouchEvents() {
        synchronized (this) {
            int len = touchEvents.size();
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                touchEventPool.free(touchEvents.get(i));
            touchEvents.clear();
            touchEvents.addAll(touchEventsBuffer);
            touchEventsBuffer.clear();
            return touchEvents;
        }
    }

    // returns the index for a given pointerId or -1 if no index.
    private int getIndex(int pointerId) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOUCHPOINTS; i++) {
            if (id[i] == pointerId) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```